# Angular 9 does not show me a list but in Postman I see it

Tags: java, spring-boot, angular9

I am making an application with Angular 9 and SpringBoot in the backend, the problem I have is that it does not show a list of people from the database (mysql), but when I use Postman, it brings me the data, Chrome tells me: zone -evergreen.js: 2845 GET http: // localhost: 4200 / example01 / people 404 (Not Found),
this is my example source code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Persona } from '../model/Persona';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonaService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  conexion:string = '/ejemplo01/personas'

  getPersonas(){
    return this.http.get<Persona[]>(this.conexion)
  }
}
```

Comment: did backend developer enable CORS on server side?

Comment: It is strange: in code you have `conexion:string = '/ejemplo01/personas'`, but in text you provide path `example01/people`. Which is correct?

Comment: Hi, in this case, the correct is '/ejemplo01/personas/' but I don't understand why in the path we read http: // localhost: 4200 / example01 /

Comment: @silentsudo yes, in the backend I put enable CORS (it's in Spring Boot)

Comment: is `example01` name of your angular application?

Comment: in this line this.http.get<Persona[]>(this.conexion) can you replace `this.conexion` with complete url from postman